# Assigning Today's Leads to Users One by One: Need Logic Help in Executing Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, database

**Description:**

I am working on a lead management system and need assistance with the logic required to assign today's leads to users in a round-robin fashion. The goal is to assign one lead at a time to each user, ensuring that each user receives only one lead based on the leads available for the day.

**I have implemented the following code:**

```
$USERIDs = array("10", "115", "145", "222","237","239","238");

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT Count(*) AS TOTALLEADS, Lead_Id AS SingleLeadsID  FROM leads_crm WHERE Referral_ID IN ('217') AND `Assigned_to` IS NULL AND `Date_Added` >= CURDATE() AND `Date_Added` < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   $z++;
   $Lead_Id = $row['TOTALLEADS'].'<br>';
   echo $SingleLeadsID = $row['SingleLeadsID'].'<br>';

}

for ($i=0; $i <=$Lead_Id; $i++) {
    if (in_array("10", $USERIDs)) {
        $sql1 = "UPDATE leads_crm Assigned_to='10', Assigned_Date='$noww'  WHERE Lead_Id='" . $Lead_Id . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql1);
    }

    if (in_array("115", $USERIDs)) {
        $sql1 = "UPDATE leads_crm Assigned_to='115', Assigned_Date='$noww'  WHERE Lead_Id='" . $Lead_Id . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql1);
    }
}
```

In the code above, I fetch today's leads from the database and store the count in the variable $TOTALLEADS. I want to assign these leads to users listed in the $USERIDs array. However, I am uncertain about the logic required to assign each user one lead at a time before moving on to the next user.

How can I modify my code to ensure that each user receives only one lead based on the available leads for today? Should I use additional variables or loops to accomplish this? Any guidance, suggestions, or code examples would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you try with ID only, `$leadIds = array(); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {    $leadIds[] = $row['Lead_Id']; }`
and after you can foreach loop on ids.

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid i have tried it but not working

Comment: One obviously logic problem is that you are looping through all the leads before you try to do any updates. So all the code which assigns leads happens after you've already looped. Therefore it can only deal with the last lead.

Comment: @ADyson can you make any example for me thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you try and fix it based on what I've just said. Move the updates inside the while loop. Obviously you also need to move to the next user ID each time you assign a lead. So keep a variable showing the index of the user list which is to be used next. Try that and update your question with your new code if you're still stuck after that. (It ought to be trivially obvious that you can't do things to data which arrives via a loop, if you're not inside that loop!)

Comment: Please be warned that your `UPDATE` queries are highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below code it might help you.

```
$USERIDs = array("10", "115", "145", "222", "237", "239", "238");
$noww = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT Lead_Id FROM leads_crm WHERE Referral_ID IN ('217') AND `Assigned_to` IS NULL AND `Date_Added` >= CURDATE() AND `Date_Added` < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY");

$leadIds = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $leadIds[] = $row['Lead_Id'];
}

$userCount = count($USERIDs);
$leadCount = count($leadIds);
$leadsPerUser = floor($leadCount / $userCount);
$remainingLeads = $leadCount % $userCount;

$leadIndex = 0;
foreach ($USERIDs as $userId) {
    $leadsToAssign = $leadsPerUser;
    if ($remainingLeads > 0) {
        $leadsToAssign++;
        $remainingLeads--;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $leadsToAssign; $i++) {
        $leadId = $leadIds[$leadIndex];
        $sql = "UPDATE leads_crm SET Assigned_to='$userId', Assigned_Date='$noww' WHERE Lead_Id='$leadId'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        $leadIndex++;
    }
}
```

Fetch the lead IDs for today's leads that meet the criteria you specified.

Calculate the number of leads per user by dividing the total number of leads by the number of users.
Take the floor value to ensure equal distribution.

Calculate the remaining leads that need to be assigned by taking the modulo of the total number of leads with the number of users.

Iterate each user and assign the appropriate number of leads to them. If there are remaining leads, distribute them one by one until exhausted. (You can modify as per your need.)

Construct and execute the update query for each lead assigned to a user.

Comment: That must be your user id i just give an idea, that is the only solution or you can change the logic but it should be like I provided :)